# How to use TinyMCE Style dropdown to add inlinestyle?

Tags: tinymce, inline-styles

I am using TinyMCE, to customise style dropdownlist, I use "content_css" property to specify the css file I want to use, for example:
content_css: "css/example.css"

Then it will add a span with class name, for examples:

```
<span class="style1">Hello World</span>
```

But how can I tell TinyMCE Style dropdownlist to add a span with **inline style** property instead of a class name? something like:

```
<span style="color:#E01B6A; font-size:12px;background-color:#D6D4D5;">Hello World</span>
```

The reason is I need to output the html code without the css file reference, inline style is required.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer by myself on TinyMCE website - can just use **style_formats** to list all inline styles

```
 // Style formats 
        style_formats: [
            { title: 'style1', inline: 'span', styles: { 'color': '#E01B6A','font-size':'12px','background-color':'#D6D4D5'} },
            { title: 'style2', inline: 'span', styles: { 'color': '#6F7575','font-size':'14px','background-color':'#ABF5EC'} },
            { title: 'style3', inline: 'span', styles: { 'color': '#000000','font-size':'16px','background-color':'#8357F2', 'font-weight':'bold'} }
         ],
```